# Can I Inject XML into XML files using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, typescript

What I am looking for is something like `.innerXML(<bar>foo</bar>)` where I can pass in XML code.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser